# .Net Core 3.1 Cookie Authentication logout looping

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, plesk, .net-core-3.1

I am using cookie authentication in the application. After logging in, the cookie is not deleted, but constantly redirects to the login page. It works fine on the local machine but when I deploy it to plesk panel it constantly redirects to the login page.

here are the codes (Startup.cs):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
        services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));
        services.AddDependencyResolvers(new ICoreModule[]
        {
            new CoreModule()
        });

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddCookie(options => { options.LoginPath = "/Auth/Login"; });

        services.AddControllersWithViews();
 }
```

login page codes:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AutoValidateAntiforgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(UserForLoginDto model)
    {
        var user = _authService.Login(model);

        if (!user.Success)
        {
            ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Email veya şifre hatalı";
            return View(model);
        }

        if (!user.Data.Status)
        {
            ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Email adresinizi onaylayınız";
            return View(model);
        }

        var nameIdentifier = new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, model.Email);
        var userIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim> { nameIdentifier }, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(userIdentity);

        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, claimsPrincipal);

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Order");
    }
```

logout page codes:

```
    [Authorize]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
    {
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Login");
    }
```

Comment: I don't delete the cookie anyway.  But when I try to enter my action methods with the attribute of authorize, it leads to the exit screen, although I am still authanticate.

Comment: Have you tried adding:  services.AddAuthorization(); & services.AddSession() to ConfigureServices() ?
Also: app.UseAuthentication(); & app.UseAuthorization(); in Configure()